# How do I get json element from script tag on web page?

Tags: javascript, python, json, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the json element from a page:

```
   import json
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

    url='https://www.nemlig.com/varer/dagligvarer/frugt-og-groent/frugt-baer'
    url

    page = requests.get(url)
    soupH = bs(page.content, 'html.parser')

    scripts=soupH.find_all('script')

    p=re.compile('contentAsJson')

    cn=0
    cont_js=""
    for sc in scripts:
        cn+=1
        #print(cn,sc)
        if p.search(str(sc)):
            cont_js=sc
            #print(cont_js)

    cont_js
```

**But how do i extract the vaalues of (Id, PoductGroupId and CombinedProductsAndSitecoreTimestamp) from the json script?**

cont_js returns this:

> var contentAsJson = { "MetaData":
>   {"Id":"f905e457-c461-4750-880b-bbe6f2d5f5eb","Name":"Frugt-baer","DisplayName":"","TemplateId":"25997ff0-7455-4d0f-bd48-3de2f3a5c3d8","TemplateName":"Filter
>   page","Versions":1,"Language":"da","ContentPath":"/Site/Varer/Dagligvarer/Frugt-og-groent/Frugt-baer","FullPath":"/sitecore/content/Site/Varer/Dagligvarer/Frugt-og-groent/Frugt-baer","Path":"/sitecore/content/Site/Varer/Dagligvarer/Frugt-og-groent/Frugt-baer","Url":"https://www.nemlig.com/varer/dagligvarer/frugt-og-groent/frugt-baer","Header":"Frugt
>   og bær","AutoHideMobileNavigation":false,"PageTitle":"Oversigt over
>   frugt og bær - Dagligvarer når det passer dig!","MetaKeyWords":"Frugt
>   og bær","MetaDescription":"Udvalg af frugt og bær hos nemlig.com -
>   Modtag dagligvarer når det passer dig, levering direkte til døren. Køb
>   frugt og bær hos
>   nemlig.com","CategoryPath":null,"BackgroundImageForJson":null,"ResponseCode":200,"NavigationTitle":"Oversigt
>   over frugt og bær - Dagligvarer når det passer
>   dig!","IncludeInNavigation":true,"IncludeInSitemap":true,"TopAdvertisement":null,"LeftAdvertisement":null,"MenuContextId":"f905e457-c461-4750-880b-bbe6f2d5f5eb","TrackingId":"f905e457-c461-4750-880b-bbe6f2d5f5eb","AuthenticationRequired":false},
>   "Settings":
>   {"BuildVersion":"b64.2.0.0","SitecorePublishedStamp":"4M-2z7ue","ProductsImportedTimestamp":"4BNhsQiH","CombinedProductsAndSitecoreTimestamp":"4BNhsQiH-4M-2z7ue","UserId":null,"ZipCode":"0","DeliveryZoneId":1,"TimeslotUtc":"2017052108-60-600","StaticResourcesPath":"https://live.nemligstatic.com/s/b64.2.0.0/scom/dist"},
>   
>   "content":[{"Id":"ca3b1f74-a65e-41ce-9df7-6d6380d4a895","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Bær","ProductGroupId":"e588f992-c387-44b4-95ed-fc7e385796e7","TotalProducts":11},{"Id":"c6d7c49e-7d54-4a6c-917b-2f14725a87d2","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Udskåret
>   frugt","ProductGroupId":"0bba003e-4cd0-4161-ba43-3dd90c0e9095","TotalProducts":5},{"Id":"9f7d5644-c3f0-4cd2-8324-8d23530cb95d","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Eksotisk
>   frugt","ProductGroupId":"14069d07-9bf1-4651-ba04-744da98ea9d6","TotalProducts":20},{"Id":"7e0c336f-78b1-41d6-beab-b02b824a22d0","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Druer,
>   kiwi og
>   stenfrugter","ProductGroupId":"6c777f89-fbb2-4d33-b170-6e2586009a16","TotalProducts":12},{"Id":"62e71c2b-1feb-4771-a7e0-2cbfc70a7326","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Meloner","ProductGroupId":"131a255e-437b-43f5-97b6-0e214ab33a0f","TotalProducts":10},{"Id":"ad2dc012-ad6f-458a-91a2-8770bdcdaa0c","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Citrusfrugt","ProductGroupId":"ea195351-c44a-4158-85f0-4cfbb890978b","TotalProducts":11},{"Id":"3aa05883-2d23-4e1c-8bb1-67acdf3cfc17","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Pærer","ProductGroupId":"dc604784-c871-4d0e-bc88-2e6ceb8ac044","TotalProducts":4},{"Id":"0cd2cb71-5ace-479b-ad69-aefb01100bbd","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Bananer","ProductGroupId":"97e40d96-bbee-4a32-89e8-d2d05e522b7e","TotalProducts":4},{"Id":"b815f5ef-2d2a-44f6-bedd-0704101b1836","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistshowallspot","TemplateId":"15135d3e-4a63-478c-ac4d-d3705963ced0","Heading":"Æbler","ProductGroupId":"183ad2d6-6917-4268-84d7-3718f0dcc27a","TotalProducts":8},{"Id":"174835ea-c986-480c-b2ad-303cf129da12","VisibleOnMobile":true,"TemplateName":"productlistonerowspot","TemplateId":"17e165e8-b722-4da5-a0c8-8881a4ce4e8c","Heading":"Frossen
>   frugt","SeeMoreLink":{"Anchor":"","Class":"","Text":"Se al frossen
>   frugt","Query":"","Title":"Se al frossen
>   frugt","Url":"/varer/dagligvarer/frost/groent-frugt-frost/frugt-og-baer","Target":"","TargetId":"cd577472-03d9-4ddc-8fc6-632e6d72b30c","Type":"internal"},"ProductGroupId":"426f6f21-91e5-4101-9867-0e7a2aa29bd4","TotalProducts":19},{"Id":"0b855f72-b3e8-4bd1-bc23-61cbda4c7002","TemplateName":"recipelistonerowspot","TemplateId":"f804ee41-029a-4dfe-9247-4fe8c421e637","Heading":"Årstidens
>   frugt- og
>   grøntpakker","SeeMoreLink":{"Anchor":"","Class":"","Text":"Aarstidens-frugt-og-groent-pakker","Query":"","Title":"","Url":"/varer/dagligvarer/frugt-og-groent/aarstidens-frugt-og-groent-pakker","Target":"","TargetId":"72c3abce-d57a-45db-9dcb-39ad103a848e","Type":"internal"},"RecipeGroupId":"a222d64e-a5f1-44ed-8dbd-21b8f643ef63","ContextId":"baer","TotalRecipes":6}],
>   "aside":[  ] };

Comment: In JS you can use JSON.parse(jsonString). In python it can be done with json.loads(json_string)

Comment: Thanx., I can see that works on a  json_string only containing json. But how do I extract the json code from the sring returned by cont_js above?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the example you gave - you have string cont_js which contains something like this:

```
'var contentAsJson = {...encoded string...}'
```

To get **only** json encoded string, cut it:

```
json_string = cont_js[20:]
```

Decode JSON:

```
decoded_string = json.loads(json_string)
```

And then you can access your data:

```
id = decoded_string['MetaData']['Id']
```

Comment: bs4.element.Tag

Comment: I get TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'. cont_js is a bs4.element.tag

Comment: If I try to string it: cont_js.string    then iI get a string looking  like this:

Comment: '\r\n\t\t\tvar contentAsJson = {\r\n"MetaData": {"Id":"f905e457-c461-4750-880b-bbe6f2d5f5eb","Name":"Frugt-baer","DisplayName":"","TemplateId":"25997ff0-7455-4d0f-bd48-3de2f3a5c3d8","TemplateName":"Filter page","Versions":1,"Language":"da","ContentPath":"/Site/Varer/Dagligvarer/Frugt-og-groent/Frugt-

Comment: how do I get it to look "clean"?

Comment: `conj_js = cont_js.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\t','')`